# How to get from the string substring after second hyphen?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have three and more hyphens in string I need to get from the string substring after second hyphen.

For example, I have this string:

```
"someStr1 - someStr2 - someStr3 - someStr4"
```

As you can see it has 3 hyphens, I need to get from string above substring:

```
"someStr3 - someStr4"
```

I know that I need to get the index position of second hyphen and then I can use substring function 
But I don't know how to check if there is more then 3 hyphens and how to check thet position is of the second hyphen.

Comment: please show what you have tried to do. What was the result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the RegEx [`(?<=([^-]*-){2}).*`](https://regex101.com/r/YJWDmQ/1)

- `(?<=([^-]*-){2})` makes sure there is 2 `-` before your match

  - `(?<= ... )` is a positive lookbehind
  - `[^-]*` matches anything but a `-`, 0 or more times
  - `-` matches `-` literally
- `.*` matches anything after those 2 dashes.

[**Demo.**](https://regex101.com/r/YJWDmQ/1)

```js
const data = "someStr1 - someStr2 - someStr3 - someStr4";
console.log(/(?<=([^-]*-){2}).*/.exec(data)[0]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Split string to array with `-` and check if `array.length > 3` which means at least three `-` in the string. If true, join the array from `index == 2` to the end with `-` and trim the string.

```js
var text = "someStr1 - someStr2 - someStr3 - someStr4"
var textArray = text.split('-')
if(textArray.length>3){
  console.log(textArray.slice(2).join('-').trim())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
var testStr = "someStr1 - someStr2 - someStr3 - someStr4";
var hyphenCount = testStr.match(/-/g).length;
if(hyphenCount > 2){
    var reqStr = testStr.split('-').slice(-2).join('-');
    console.log(reqStr) // logs "someStr3 - someStr4"
}
```